# Flask Many to Many loop through id to insert data to table not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to append data to table

```
>>> paper = ['1', '2']
>>> work = Work(name="Sample", cost="500")
>>> db.session.add(work)
>>> for pape1 in paper:
>>>     paper1 = Paper.query.filter_by(id=pape1).first()
>>>     paper1.pages.append(work)
>>>     db.session.add(paper1)
>>>     db.session.commit()
```

**models.py**

```
papers = db.Table('papers',
    db.Column('work_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('work.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('paper_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('paper.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Work(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(90), nullable=False)
    page = db.relationship('Paper', secondary=papers, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True), uselist=False)
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Paper(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(90), nullable=False)
```

I think i should get something like this.

```
  work_id  |  paper_id
  ---------|-----------
1 1        | 1          
  ---------|-----------
2 1        | 2
```

But i am getting this.
papers table

**figure 1.**

```
  work_id  |  paper_id
  ---------|-----------
1 1        | 2          
  ---------------------
```

The paper with id=2 is once getting linked with the work with id=1.
But when i started debugging. i saw that after first loop it adds to the papers table. Like this.

**figure 2.**

```
  work_id  |  paper_id
  ---------|-----------
1 1        | 1        
  ---------------------
```

But after the second loop, i think it updates it from figure 2 to figure 1. I don't know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This question help me to imagine my case, thanks a lot Man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `uselist` to `False`. *Don't do that*, you told SQLAlchemy that the `page` attribute should be a *scalar*, a single element:

```
page = db.relationship('Paper', secondary=papers, lazy='subquery',
    backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True), uselist=False)
```

From the [`relationship` documentation for `uselist`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.uselist):

> a boolean that indicates if this property should be loaded as a list or a scalar. In most cases, this value is determined automatically by `relationship()` at mapper configuration time, based on the type and direction of the relationship - one to many forms a list, many to one forms a scalar, many to many is a list. If a scalar is desired where normally a list would be present, such as a bi-directional one-to-one relationship, set `uselist` to `False`.

You want to *not set the attribute* and leave it to SQLAlchemy to determine what it should be. For a many-to-many relationship you really want it to be `True`, and that's the automatic result when you leave it out:

```
page = db.relationship('Paper', secondary=papers, lazy='subquery',
    backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))
```

Comment: Thanks. @Martijn Pieters